# How to echo a line of bash to file without executing?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'm currently trying to write a bash script from within another bash script. 
I do the following:

```
touch /home/file.sh
echo "#!/bin/bash" >> /home/file.sh
echo "for line in $(grep -o 'guest-......' /etc/passwd | sort -u); do sudo deluser $line; done >> /home/file.sh
```

The problem is that echo not only writes to file but executes part of the for loop. So the file content becomes something like the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in guest-rbrars; do sudo deluser ; done
```

Instead of:

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in $(grep -o 'guest-......' /etc/passwd | sort -u); do sudo deluser $line; done >> /var/log/cron 2>&1
```

How do I get to push that for loop to a file without executing part of it?

Thank you!

Best regards

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape all the special symbols. The `$` symbol is special because it represents a variable name, or a code block inside the parentheses. So if you run it, bash will try to run it first *in the script that contains the writing code* and then write the result to your file (`/home/file.sh`).

To escape a symbol, use the `\` symbol. For example:

```
echo "for line in \$(grep -o 'guest-......' /etc/passwd | sort -u); do sudo deluser \$line; done" >> /home/file.sh
```